# Is it possible that when click button addclass on another html page

Tags: jquery

Is it possible that when click button addclass on another html page using jquery ?

for example,

a.html

```
<button class="btn_click">When click, add 'active' class on b.html</button>
```

b.html

```
<div class="active">active</div>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Not on another HTML page, no (that would be a huge security vulnerability). What you could do is utilise a link with a `GET` variable, and then check for the presence of that variable to add the class :)

Answer (score 0):

Without a server side intermediary that wouldn't be possible. You'd need to send the results of the button click to the server which would then update some value and it could either be pushed from there to another page or the other page could poll for it and ask for changes.

Think of it this way. In Facebook, if you're on two different computers and  you send a message to someone, the message you sent shows up on the other computer also. But there are obviously servers involved.

But to send directly? No. I suppose it MIGHT be possible if they were two pages or tabs in the same browser on the same computer and you used a browser plugin. Otherwise, there would be huge security risks if it was possible another way.